# how to access jar inside trunk folder in artifactory using gradle

Tags: gradle, artifactory, dependency-management

We have two below jars and respective path in our artifactory

1. idl-enginex-cache-1.0.201906200816.jar

http://artifactory.mycomp.com/artifactory/ctmodules-local/com/mycomp/idl-enginex-cache/**trunk**/1.0.201906200816/idl-enginex-cache-1.0.201906200816.jar

2. idl-enginex-api-trunk.1.0.201911130401.jar

http://artifactory.mycomp.com/artifactory/ctmodules-local/com/mycomp/idl-enginex-api/trunk.1.0.201911130401/idl-enginex-api-trunk.1.0.201911130401.jar

And in my gradle file

```
implementation ("com.mycomp:idl-enginex-cache:1.0.201906200816")
implementation ("com.mycomp:idl-enginex-api:trunk.1.0.201911130401")
```

When i do gradle build, it is says **could not able to resolve 
com.mycomp:idl-enginex-cache:1.0.201906200816**. However, i have no issues with  idl-enginex-api jar.

Only difference i see is the difference in the artifactory path idl-enginex-cache:1.0.201906200816.jar is inside trunk folder.

How to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The `/com/mycomp/idl-enginex-cache/trunk/1.0.201906200816/idl-enginex-cache-1.0.201906200816.jar` path does not conform to the [Maven repository layout](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Remote+repository+layout).
The Maven 2/3 layout mapped artifacts from a `groupId:artifactId:version:classifier:type` to a repository path using the following scheme:

```
${groupId.replace('.','/')}/${artifactId}/${version}/${artifactId}-${version}${classifier==null?'':'-'+classifier}.${type}
```

In your case, the mapping is the following:

- groupId - com.mycomp
- artifactsId - idl-enginex-cache
- version - 1.0.201906200816

The "trunk" path of the path is the one which is not according to the layout.
You should change the artifact path in Artifactory, not to include the "trunk" part.